# Beginner: How do I check if 4 tokens are in a row, column and or a diagonal to declare a winner in my Connect 4 Game

Tags: java, string, connect-four

I was wondering on how to check for 4 Rs or Ys are in a row, column and diagonal to declare a winner (using strings shown below in code) for my Connect 4 game, I have spent 5 hours trying to figure it out but I'm still too new to coding to understand what to do. Please do keep all the code that exists below (please don't use private class or anything a beginner wouldn't know since its being handed in to my teacher).
thank you to anyone that has commented and given me their response.

```
package finalproject;


import java.util.*;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class ConnectFour

{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println("Welcome to Connect 4, \n\nObjective:\nBe the first player to get four of your colored checkers in a row- in any direction.\nRemember, you have to drop your circle to the very bottom row, you can't leave circles floating in random areas.");
    String [] tokenColor = {"R","Y"};
    //methods arrays
    int playerselect = menu();
    System.out.println("Im in main");
    int currentPlayer = players(1);



    //arrays for each column of the board
    String [] column1 = {"O","O","O","O","O","O"};
    String [] column2 = {"O","O","O","O","O","O"};
    String [] column3 = {"O","O","O","O","O","O"};
    String [] column4 = {"O","O","O","O","O","O"};
    String [] column5 = {"O","O","O","O","O","O"};
    String [] column6 = {"O","O","O","O","O","O"};
    String [] column7 = {"O","O","O","O","O","O"};


    for (int i = 1; i<=42; i++)
    {
        //using a for loop to to change the board after every player move
        printboard(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7);

        System.out.println("before placement");
        tokenPlacement(tokenColor[currentPlayer], column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7);
        System.out.println("after placement");

        printboard(column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7);
        currentPlayer = players(currentPlayer);
        
        
        
    }

    




}





public static void printboard(String[] column1, String[] column2, String[] column3, String[] column4,
        String[] column5, String[] column6, String[] column7) 
{
    System.out.println(1234567);
    //prints out board using loop
    for (int i = 5; i>=0; i--) 
    {
        System.out.print(column1[i]);
        System.out.print(column2[i]);
        System.out.print(column3[i]);
        System.out.print(column4[i]);
        System.out.print(column5[i]);
        System.out.print(column6[i]);
        System.out.print(column7[i]);
        System.out.println();
    }

}



public static int menu() 
{ 
    //enters menu method



    //scanner looks for next input from user

    Scanner myInput = new Scanner (System.in);
    int playerX;

    //prints out menu, this menu give the user the option to pick either P1, P2 or to exit the game
    System.out.println("\nUse the corresponding numbers below to choose a eaither a player, or to exit the program.\n (Note that when you choose player 1 you will always go first)");
    System.out.println("\n            1.   Choose player 1 (R)" );
    System.out.println("            2.   Choose player 2 (Y)");
    System.out.println("            3.   Exit");
    System.out.println("\n                 Select an option");
    playerX = myInput.nextInt();

    //if statements for player selection
    if (playerX == 1)
    {   
        System.out.println("You are Red");
        System.out.println("\nPlayer 2 is Yellow");


    }

    else if (playerX == 2) 
    {

        System.out.println("You are Yellow");
        System.out.println("\nPlayer 2 is Red");

    }
    //exits program
    else if (playerX == 3)
    {
        System.out.println("You didn't choose a player! Shutting Down connect_four.exe");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    //exits program
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, I dont't understand? Please re-run the program and choose again.");
        System.exit(0);
    }


    return playerX;






}//end menu


public static int players(int currentPlayer) {
    System.out.println("Im in the players method");



    //displays and decides who's turn it is 
    if (currentPlayer == 0)
    {
        currentPlayer = (1);
        System.out.println("\nIt's Yellow's Turn");
    }

    else if (currentPlayer == 1)
    {
        currentPlayer = (0);
        System.out.println("\nIt's Red's Turn");
    }


    System.out.println(currentPlayer);


    //loops on who goes


    return currentPlayer;   

}//end players  
public static void tokenPlacement(String tokenColor, String [] column1, String [] column2, String [] column3, String [] column4, String [] column5, String [] column6, String [] column7) 
{
    //scans for user's next input
    Scanner myInput = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("\nOut of the 7 columns above, choose a number between 1-7 to signify which column you choose");
    int columnChoice = myInput.nextInt();
    boolean placed = false;
    //if statement that runs a for loop if columnChoice/users's input == 1
    if (columnChoice == 1)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++) 
        {   
            //looks to see if the selected slot has a "O" and if so prints out either a "R" or a "Y" dependent of what player you are
            if (column1[i].equals("O")) 
            {
                column1[i] = tokenColor;
                placed = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        //if a whole column if filled with "R"s or "Y"s tell the user to choose a different column
        if (!placed)
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry that column is full. Choose another column");
            tokenPlacement(tokenColor, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7);
        }
    }




    else if (columnChoice == 2)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++) 
        {   
            //looks to see if the selected slot has a "O" and if so prints out either a "R" or a "Y" dependent of what player you are
            if (column2[i].equals("O")) 
            {
                column2[i] = tokenColor;
                placed = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        //if a whole column if filled with "R"s or "Y"s tell the user to choose a different column
        if (!placed)
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry that column is full. Choose another column");
            tokenPlacement(tokenColor, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7);
        }
    }




    else if (columnChoice == 3)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++) 
        {   
            //looks to see if the selected slot has a "O" and if so prints out either a "R" or a "Y" dependent of what player you are
            if (column3[i].equals("O")) 
            {
                column3[i] = tokenColor;
                placed = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        //if a whole column if filled with "R"s or "Y"s tell the user to choose a different column
        if (!placed)
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry that column is full. Choose another column");
            tokenPlacement(tokenColor, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7);
        }
    }



    else if (columnChoice == 4)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++) 
        {   
            //looks to see if the selected slot has a "O" and if so prints out either a "R" or a "Y" dependent of what player you are
            if (column4[i].equals("O")) 
            {
                column4[i] = tokenColor;
                placed = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        //if a whole column if filled with "R"s or "Y"s tell the user to choose a different column
        if (!placed)
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry that column is full. Choose another column");
            tokenPlacement(tokenColor, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7);
        }
    }




    else if (columnChoice == 5)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++) 
        {   
            if (column5[i].equals("O")) 
            {
                column5[i] = tokenColor;
                placed = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        //if a whole column if filled with "R"s or "Y"s tell the user to choose a different column
        if (!placed)
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry that column is full. Choose another column");
            tokenPlacement(tokenColor, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7);
        }
    }




    else if (columnChoice == 6)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++) 
        {   
            //looks to see if the selected slot has a "O" and if so prints out either a "R" or a "Y" dependent of what player you are
            if (column6[i].equals("O")) 
            {
                column6[i] = tokenColor;
                placed = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        //if a whole column if filled with "R"s or "Y"s tell the user to choose a different column
        if (!placed)
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry that column is full. Choose another column");
            tokenPlacement(tokenColor, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7);
        }
    }



    else if (columnChoice == 7)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<=5; i++) 
        {   
            //looks to see if the selected slot has a "O" and if so prints out either a "R" or a "Y" dependent of what player you are
            if (column7[i].equals("O")) 
            {
                column7[i] = tokenColor;
                placed = true;
                break;
            }

        }
        //if a whole column if filled with "R"s or "Y"s tell the user to choose a different column
        if (!placed)
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry that column is full. Choose another column");
            tokenPlacement(tokenColor, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7);
        }
    }








}//end tokenPlacement



}//end main
```

Comment: You would do yourself a great service if you represented the board as a single `String[][]` (2D array) variable, instead of as an individual `String[]` variable for each column.

Comment: I suggest you remove the question, make the change @KevinAnderson recommends and then repost if you still can't get it working. It'll make your code much simpler and easier for responders to help you.

Comment: Write a separate method for a horizontal check, a vertical check, an upward diagonal check, and a downward diagonal check.  Call the 4 methods for each board position.

Answer (score 0):

Write a separate method for a horizontal check, a vertical check, an upward diagonal check, and a downward diagonal check. Call the 4 methods for each board position. – **Gilbert Le Blanc 10 hours ago**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   String [] [] board = new String[6][7];

   //set everything on the board to zero
    for (int i =0; i< board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            board[i][j] = "0";
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    //assign a random winning situation
    board[3][2] = "Y";
    board[3][3] = "Y";
    board[3][4] = "Y";
    board[3][5] = "Y";
    board[3][1] = "R";
    board[2][2] = "R";
    board[1][3] = "R";
    board[0][4] = "R";
    board[4][5] = "Y";
    board[3][4] = "Y";
    board[2][3] = "Y";
    board[1][2] = "Y";
    board[3][1] = "R";
    board[2][1] = "R";
    board[1][1] = "R";
    board[0][1] = "R";
    board[2][5] = "Y";
    board[1][5] = "Y";
    board[4][3] = "Y";
    board[5][2] = "Y";
    //print board
    printBoard(board);
    //check for right row
    System.out.println(isRightRowContain4(board,3,2));
    //check for up-right-diagonal
    System.out.println(isUpRightDiagonalContain4(board,3,1));
    //check for up-left-diagonal
    System.out.println(isUpLeftDiagonalContain4(board,4,5));
    //check for up-column
    System.out.println(isUpColumnContain4(board,3,1));
    //check for down-column
    System.out.println(isDownColumnContain4(board,1,5));
    //check for left row
    System.out.println(isLeftRowContain4(board,3,5));
    //down-left-diagonal
    System.out.println(isDownLeftDiagonalContain4(board,2,5));
    //down-right-diagonal
    System.out.println(isDownRightDiagonalContain4(board,1,2));
}
public static void printBoard(String [][] board){
    for (int i =0; i< board.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<board[i].length; j++){
           System.out.print(board[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public static boolean isRightRowContain4(String [] [] board,int row, int col){
    boolean result = false;
    int count =0;
    String tokenValue = board[row][col];

    for(int k=0; k<4; k++) {
        if (tokenValue.equalsIgnoreCase(board[row][col + k])) {
            count++;
        }
    }
       if (count == 4)
           result = true;

    return result;
}
public static boolean isLeftRowContain4(String [] [] board,int row, int col){
    boolean result = false;
    int count =0;
    String tokenValue = board[row][col];

    for(int k=0; k<4; k++) {
        if (tokenValue.equalsIgnoreCase(board[row][col - k])) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 4)
        result = true;

    return result;
}
public static boolean isUpRightDiagonalContain4(String [] [] board,int row, int col){
    boolean result = false;
    int count =0;
    String tokenValue = board[row][col];
    for(int k=0; k<4; k++) {
        if (tokenValue.equalsIgnoreCase(board[row-k][(col+k)])) {
                count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 4)
        result = true;

    return result;
}
public static boolean isUpLeftDiagonalContain4(String [] [] board,int row, int col){
    boolean result = false;
    int count =0;
    String tokenValue = board[row][col];
    for(int k=0; k<4; k++) {
        if (tokenValue.equalsIgnoreCase(board[row-k][(col-k)])) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 4)
        result = true;

    return result;
}
public static boolean isUpColumnContain4(String [] [] board,int row, int col) {
    boolean result = false;
    int count = 0;
    String tokenValue = board[row][col];
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        if (tokenValue.equalsIgnoreCase(board[row - k][col])) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 4)
        result = true;

    return result;
}
public static boolean isDownColumnContain4(String [] [] board,int row, int col) {
    boolean result = false;
    int count = 0;
    String tokenValue = board[row][col];
    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        if (tokenValue.equalsIgnoreCase(board[row + k][col])) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 4)
        result = true;

    return result;
}
public static boolean isDownRightDiagonalContain4(String [] [] board,int row, int col){
    boolean result = false;
    int count =0;
    String tokenValue = board[row][col];
    for(int k=0; k<4; k++) {
        if (tokenValue.equalsIgnoreCase(board[row+k][(col+k)])) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 4)
        result = true;

    return result;
}
public static boolean isDownLeftDiagonalContain4(String [] [] board,int row, int col){
    boolean result = false;
    int count =0;
    String tokenValue = board[row][col];
    for(int k=0; k<4; k++) {
        if (tokenValue.equalsIgnoreCase(board[row+k][(col-k)])) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 4)
        result = true;

    return result;
}
```